# "Access denied" When making a folder via Microsoft Graph

Tags: php, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

When trying to make a folder in SharePoint site I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "accessDenied",
    "message": "Access denied",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "61d3b5aa-857e-4ee2-9d0d-51d235ca7c5f",
      "date": "2020-05-18T06:31:54"
    }
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. When using the Microsoft Graph Explorer, the request works.
2. Other requests to Graph endpoints work.
3. I used `msgraph-sdk-php` to make requests.
4. This usually has to do with permissions, but my user has the following
   permissions set in azure:

   ```
   Sites.Manage.All    Delegated.
   Sites.Read.All      Delegated.
   Sites.ReadWrite.All Delegated.
   ```
5. inside my.env I have the following permissions:

   ```
   OAUTH_SCOPES='openid profile offline_access user.read calendars.readwrite mail.readwrite mail.send'
   ```
6. Url:

   ```
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?%20state={someState}%20&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20user.read%20calendars.readwrite%20mail.readwrite%20mail.send%20&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/office365/token/store%20&client_id={myclientId}
   ```

What causes an error here?

Comment: @kerbholz Thank you, I use  msgraph-sdk-php to send the requests. Maybe this is relevant.

Comment: Can you take a look at what actually gets sent down the wire ? Have a look at this: https://mihai-albert.com/2020/05/13/using-microsoft-graph-to-modify-excel-files-stored-in-sharepoint-online-with-c/#fiddler-for-access-denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build special url and give it to global admin to consent.
Here is example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent

After consent is done, it may take up to 24 hours until you get your permissions. 
Also, you can check oauth token here: https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add one or more of the required scopes (Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Manage.All) in your OAUTH_SCOPES variable:

```php
OAUTH_SCOPES='Sites.Manage.All ...'
```

So that your authorization URL is built like this:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=Sites.Manage.All ...&client_id=...`

PS: None of the aformentioned scopes require [admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#sites-permissions).

Answer (score 1):

You may have requested those permissions, but until you receive "consent" from an Administrator they will not be activated.

AAD has two forms of "consent": Admin and User. If a scope requires Admin Consent, then you need to obtain that consent *before* you can obtain User consent. All of the `Sites.*.All` scopes you've listed require Admin Consent.

You can find more details about consent (and how to obtain it) from [Understanding Azure AD application consent experiences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience)

Comment: From what i understand i must make a get request and ask for additional privileges? Is there a way to just allow an admin user all privileges?

Comment: You must request all the scopes you need as part of the authentication flow. If the user authenticating is a Global Admin, they can consent to any scope (i.e. Admin's don't require Admin Consent).